# Jquery ajax form submitting twice

Tags: jquery, ajax, double-submit-problem

I am having a problem with an ajax form submitting twice. I have read numerous forums and tried removing the document.ready function. Tried to unbind my form - which broke it all together. Its an image upload form. Once a user has uploaded a file, they have the option to upload another. This then uploads twice (gives two alerts).

I have put my javascript here - http://pastebin.com/ryQr5E9e

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify - is the first upload OK? It's when you give the option to upload another that there is a problem?

Comment: Yep. The first upload is fine. The second file uploads...but twice. In the script it puts the filename in an input (artwork1 or artwork 2 etc). When uploading the second file it uploads it into artwork2 and artwork3. :-(

Comment: Try adding some console debug statements to see how you are traversing your code (or use a debugger). Something will jump out at you when you do...

Comment: Please review: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write this line $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); at line no 24.
this form automatically submitted when click on submit buttom.